# Clear up the [clear] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[clear](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/clear) is another undefined tag that is used is multiple ways:

- the "Clear" command in a number of command languages
- To empty various lists like history, cache, or cookies
- Clear (TM)  brand hardware
- to blank an entry field or spreadsheet cell
- clear the screen
- ClearType (TM) font improvement (already exists as [cleartype]; wrong tag selection)

As a catch-all, it doesn't provide much value, but it could be useful if broken into more specific tags such as:

- [clear-command](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/clear-command)
- [clear-screen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/clear-screen) - the tag [blank-screen] already exists and is used to mean both an error condition and clearing the screen.  The latter could be migrated to [clear-screen]
- [clear-brand-hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/clear-brand-hardware)
- [clear-entry](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/clear-entry)
- I'm stuck on a generic term for clearing lists that people would think to use.  There is an existing [purge](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/purge) tag, but that probably isn't the best (another undefined tag)